# How to resolve npm error: npm start not working

Tags: npm, development-environment, npm-scripts, npm-start

i am trying to install "npx create-react-app new" it successfully installs, however "npm start" shows error:

```
PS D:\react project\new> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\react project\new/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\react project\new\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-15T08_51_51_601Z-debug.log
PS D:\react project\new>
```

I checked my package.json, it looks fine, anyone can suggest whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all run:

```
npm run start
```

if it did not work then delete the node-module folder and use

```
npm i or npm install
```

this will work for you.